# How to select alternative sources for current API in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I am currently trying Android-R previews SDK on Android Studio, which does not have available SDK sources released yet. Unlike the "class not matching source" case, which will have an "alternative source available for class...", I don't find this option in my case. Please refer to the screenshot below.

As most of the classes (interfaces) will still remain almost same as they are on the API level 29 SDK, which I have already installed and have sources downloaded. How can I tell Android Studio to use another source when it cannot find one to match the version?

Thanks a lot.

[image: AndroidStudio Source Not Available]

Comment: Android Studio version ?

Comment: The version is latest 3.6